# Web app and creation of schemas when registering users

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, saas

I am developing a SAAS app using asp.net MVC and sql server 2008 as the backend server.

When users register i want them to have a unique url which will in turn create a new schema with all the new tables under that new schema.

My question is that would this be an efficient way of achieving this? i.e. create all schemas etc when they register. Dont want them waiting to register as it needs to be responsive?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on how complex is your schema and the amount of data that you are looking at pre-populating. Another option is to have data of all tenants stored in one common schema which will be very responsive. I have created a very simple SAAS starter kit with this shared schema structure using ASP.Net MVC 3 / MySQL / twitter bootstrap 1 which is available at http://yatendra.github.com/saasapp/ if you want take a look.